# Firebase Quota exceeded working on my app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, native, quota

I'm working on my react native app for a university project and today I got this error:

[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Quota exceeded.]

And when I open firebase I can't see my database, I see an error during the loading files.

I created the firebase project yesterday, and if I check the reads and writes I see 1605 reads and 3 writes.

Yesteday I had the same issue and I solved it by creating a new database and connect it again to my react native app, but I can't do this every day, how can I work on it without having this trouble anymore?

Comment: You can check [Firebase quotas and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas) but they are pretty high. With the limit _5000 requests per 100 seconds_ you might have some serious problem with your application (endless re-rendering and making new requests?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the problems are caused by the timestamp methods, when I try to read the createdAt label and to convert it with getDate I get too many reads